# Cauchy sequences and condition $X_{n+1} – X_n\to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence and suppose that the sequence $\{X_{n+1} – X_n\}$ converges to $0$. Give an example to show that the sequence $\{X_n\}$ may not converge. Hence, the condition that $|X_n-X_m| < \epsilon$ for all $m,n \ge N$ is crucial in the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Think of $x_{n+1} - x_{n}$ as the derivative of $x_n$.  Does a function with a derivative approaching zero need to be bounded above?

Comment: See also: [Pseudo-Cauchy sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237655), [I want an example of a sequence that satisfies $|x(n) - x(n-1)| \to 0$ but not Cauchy](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1494962), [If $\{x_n\}$ satisfies that $x_{n+1} - x_n$ goes to $0$, is $\{x_n\}$ a Cauchy sequence?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633602/if-x-n-satisfies-that-x-n1-x-n-goes-to-0-is-x-n-a-cauchy-s), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: What can you say about the partial sums of, say, the harmonic series?

Or a sequence involving $\ln{n}$?

---

More generally, think of your favorite function $f$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \infty$, but that approaches $\infty$ "slowly."

Answer (score 1):

Take the sequence $X_n = \sum_1^n \frac{1}{n}$. Here $X_{n=1} - X_n = \frac{1}{n}$ which goes to $0$ but $X_n$ is not convergent.